# Change elements input by button in web forms

Tags: html, forms

I have a problem with web forms. Since last web browsers update, my web form buttons type button, submit and reset don't work. I could resolve changing  elements by .
Can someone help me? Why is this happening?
Thanks.

Comment: Plz Share the code

Comment: For example, this code doesn't work <input type='button' value='Traspasar Direccion' name='traspasar' id='traspasar'>. But this one works right <button type='button' name='traspasar' id='traspasar'>Traspasar Direccion</button>. Thanks